# Acrobat: How to set default font for text box tool?

Tags: fonts, adobe-acrobat

How do I set the default font for the text box tool in Adobe Acrobat?

(If the solution depends on the version, assume Version 8.)

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Echo: Version 8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After configuring your desired fonts, you should be able to click in a white area of the text box and select "make current properties default". That should save your font settings.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve the same issue for a long time and now I found the solution.
I think this issue regards only Win 7 64bit users with Adobe X Pro.
So, if you want to change the default font for the textbox, and the right click and Set As Default Properties does not work, the only way is to modify value in regedit.
Don't worry about, but be really careful inside registry.

Follow these steps:

1. Close Adobe X Pro, if still opened!
2. Open Regedit and go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat\10.0\Tx Properties. There are all values about textbox properties.
3. Now double click on "sTextFont" and left click inside the box, after Helvetica. Delete the word Helvetica and type Arial. (You can check the value of any font here: http://www.asciitohex.com/).
4. Now on the left side of the window you must see the Hexadecimal value of Arial (41 72 69 61 6c). Left click after "6c" and add "00" value, that will add "." (dot) after "Arial" on the right side.
5. Now hit OK and save. Exit Regedit and you're done. Open Adobe X Pro, add an new textbox, and voila, the default font is Arial.

Enjoy!
Rene

Answer (score 0):

Using Adobe Acrobat X Pro version 10:

- Select `Tools --> Content --> Select Object`
- Right mouse click anywhere within the now highlighted fields, then select `Properties --> Appearance`
- In the `Text` dialog box, choose desired `Font Size`, `Font` and `Color` (*optional*), then select `Close`.
- When done setting font preferences, in the `Task Pane`, select `Forms --> Edit --> Close Form Editing`.

Begin filling in your form.  Press the Tab key to move through the fields.